# Gcc on OS X: Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64

Tags: c, macos, gcc

I am writing an application that has multiple subdirectories. I have created a Makefile structure such that the subdirectories compile the file and do "ar rvs" and "ranlib libxxx.a" to create archives into the parent  directory for linking.

However the "ld" command is running into the following problem.

```
ld: warning: ignoring file ./libxxx.a, file was built for archive which is not
the architecture being linked (x86_64):
./libxxx.a Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
```

I am using gcc on Mac OS X 10.10.1

I read many posts on this. I tried "gcc -arch i386", then I encounter the same error for i386

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
```

I installed gcc-4.9.2 and tried using it instead of the default gcc, with no luck. I tried using x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0-g++-4.9.2 and that did not help either.

Answer (score 2):

The errors you are seeing mean that you have a mixture of i386 and x86_64 code in the build, and you need to be consistent.  Unless there's a compelling reason to do otherwise (I'd be curious to know what it is), you should be compiling everything for 64-bit only.  Using `gcc` on Mac, that is normally the default, but you can force it by adding a `-m64` flag to the compilations.  One way of doing that is to set `CC="gcc -m64"` on the `make` command line; there are other better ways too, but the details depend on your `makefile` contents.

To resolve: first, remove all the libraries and object code you've built in your project area (maybe `make clean` will do it — if you wrote a `clean` target).  Then, fettle the value of `CC` or its flags (`CFLAGS` ultimately, but how `CFLAGS` is built depends on the `makefile`) so that 64-bit compilation is enforced.  Then make sure you're using that in all compilations.  If you don't see the `-m64`, you've got a problem.

If you must use 32-bit, substitute `-m32` for `-m64`.

The discussion above assumes you are using `gcc` to run the `ld` command.  If you are not, then you're on your own until you use `gcc` to run the `ld` command.  In my view, you've got better things to do with your life than work out how to run the `ld` command correctly; I certainly have.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I tried "CC=gcc -m64" and I have also used gcc to run the ld command.But the result is the same. I only tried -m32 option to see if it works if I make it consistent, but for no other reason.

Comment: No-one can help you much more unless we see a minimal makefile that reproduces the problem.  Read up on how to create an MCVE ([How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) or SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)) — two names and links for the same idea.  Your MCVE code should probably be one minimal source file (and header) for the library (`void libfunc(void) { printf("%s called\n", __func__); }`, and your main program calling the library function, plus one or two makefiles depending on how things are laid out.